# Url Routing Rule is conflicting

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-routing

I am implementing the URL Routing in my asp.net application, in that my some  rules are conflicting.
below is my some rules which is conflicting:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add("QuestionSubject",
    new Route("questions/{subjectname}/{pageno}",
    new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", null } },
    new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", @"^[0-9]*$" } },
    new EventRouteHandler("~/questionsitemap/subject.aspx")));

RouteTable.Routes.Add("QuestionSubjectTopic",
    new Route("questions/{subjectname}/{topicname}/{pageno}",
    new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", null } },
    new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", @"^[0-9]*$" } },
    new EventRouteHandler("~/questionsitemap/topic.aspx")));

RouteTable.Routes.Add("QuestionGrade",
    new Route("questions/{gradename}/",
    new EventRouteHandler("~/questionsitemap/grade.aspx")));

RouteTable.Routes.Add("QuestionSubjectGrade",
    new Route("questions/{gradename}/{subjectname}/",
    new EventRouteHandler("~/questionsitemap/grade.aspx")));

RouteTable.Routes.Add("QuestionSubjectTopicGrade",
    new Route("questions/{gradename}/{subjectname}/{topicname}/",
    new EventRouteHandler("~/questionsitemap/grade.aspx")));
```

In this when I am requesting to open the **QuestionGrade** rule it is calling the **QuestionSubject** because the rules are similar for both, same happened for others rule.

Please any one help me to find out the solutions for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make them more specific since the routing engine can't distinguish between `{subjectname}` and `{gradename}`. Can you use something like the following, which adds `/subject/` and `/grade/` to your routes?

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add("QuestionSubject",
    new Route("questions/subject/{subjectname}/{pageno}",
    new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", null } },
    new RouteValueDictionary { { "pageno", @"^[0-9]*$" } },
    new EventRouteHandler("~/questionsitemap/subject.aspx")));

RouteTable.Routes.Add("QuestionGrade",
    new Route("questions/grade/{gradename}/",
    new EventRouteHandler("~/questionsitemap/grade.aspx")));
```

Comment: :but my client don't want any static directory like "Subject" or "Grade"

Comment: You kind of don't have any choice if you're using routing like that.  The first "questions/{}/{}" structure is always going to win.  There has to be some other level of disambiguation.